# Laravel 4 Query Builder: LEFT JOIN ... AND ... query

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I'm trying to select all results from one table and merge with another table when user ID's match.

I have three tables: runs, users and a run_user pivot table. I want to select all results from 'runs' and additional columns in the pivot table (which are 'completed', 'sticky', 'last_tested' and 'difficulty'), but only pull data from run_user for the current user.

In raw SQL I've managed to do this via a LEFT JOIN with an AND statement:

```
SELECT
runs.startpoint,
runs.startpostcode,
runs.endpoint,
runs.endpostcode,
run_user.completed,
run_user.sticky,
run_user.last_tested,
run_user.difficulty
FROM runs
LEFT JOIN run_user ON run_user.run_id=runs.id AND run_user.user_id = '2'
```

Any suggestions how to do this via the Query Builder? I can do the LEFT JOIN in Laravel 4 but can't figure out how to combine this with an AND statement as well.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 35):

As you requested, this is how you would do your query with the query builder:

```
DB::table('runs')
        ->leftJoin('run_user', function($join)
        {
            $join->on('run_user.run_id', '=', 'runs.id')
            ->on('run_user.user_id', '=', '2');
        })
        ->get();
```

But that JOIN statement looks a bit weird, you probably want to turn that into a normal WHERE (unless you have a very specific reason to filter directly in the JOIN clause).

```
DB::table('runs')->join('run_user', 'run_user.run_id', '=', 'runs.id')->where('run_user.user_id', '=', '2')->get();
```

Docs: http://laravel.com/docs/queries#joins

Comment: Thanks, it looks as though the 'andOn' condition doesn't work with version 4 (http://laravel.com/api/class-Illuminate.Database.Query.JoinClause.html)

Comment: You are right, sorry. I edited my answer, you can do ->on()->on() to do ANDs on a JOIN.

Comment: Creating a join a field and then a where is not the same thing as 2 conditions on join.

Comment: in case if you want to pass dynamic value in place `'run_user.user_id', '=', '2'` it is giving error. for example if I try `'run_user.user_id', '=', $id` it gives undefined variable $id.

Comment: That's because $id is out of scope for the closure. Change `function($join) { ` to `function($join) use($id) {` to inject the $id variable into the closure and then use it like you wanted `run_user.user_id', '=', $id` .

Answer (score 13):

In case anyone is wondering I got this working using DB::raw on one of the leftJoin parameters:

```
DB::table('runs')
    ->leftjoin('run_user', 'runs.id','=', 
      DB::raw('run_user.run_id AND run_user.user_id = ' . $user->id))
    ->get();
```

It's not as 'eloquent' as I'd like it to be but without a working 'andOn' condition this seems to be the only way if you want to add an AND to the LEFT JOIN.

If anyone can suggest a neater way I'd love to know!

Thanks

Comment: You can do it with ->leftJoin() and a closure with ->on()->on() like I showed in my answer, which is much cleaner. Also your double JOIN clause should really be a WHERE.

Comment: I think this solution is better.

Answer (score 5):

use this

```
DB::table('runs')->select('runs.startpoint','runs.startpostcode','runs.endpoint','runs.endpostcode','run_user.completed','run_user.sticky','run_user.last_tested','run_user.difficulty')
    ->leftJoin('run_user', function($join)
    {
        $join->on('run_user.run_id', '=', 'runs.id')
        ->where('run_user.user_id', '2');
    })
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

In Laravel 4 you can do this using Eloquent query. I assume that you are aware of Eloquent relationships and know to to create models.
For your query it should be

```
RunUser::where('user_id',$id)->leftjoin('runs','runs.id','=','run_user.run_id')->first();
```

**Note** RunUser is the model for run_user table.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Unfortunately I have the same problem using the 'where' clause. This works fine for rows where the run_user table has a record for runs but doesn't get all of runs.

Comment: try changing to `Runs::where('id',$id)->leftjoin('run_user','run_user.run_id','=','runs.id')->first();`

Answer (score 0):

Provident and user Table Join and get id to all details.

```
   $return = DB::table(config::get('databaseconstants.TBL_USER'))
            ->leftjoin('inex_pf_details', 'inex_users.id', '=', 'inex_pf_details.pf_user_id')
            ->select('inex_pf_details.*','inex_users.*')
            ->where('inex_pf_details.id', $id)
            ->first();
    return $return;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is must work:

```
DB::table('runs')
        ->leftJoin('run_user', function($join) use ($user_id)
        {
            $join->on('run_user.run_id', '=', 'runs.id')
            ->where('run_user.user_id', '=', $user_id);
        })
        ->get();
```

Comment: Could you explain how this works or what it is supposed to do?